# Using Mongodb and mapreduce to create a list with sub items

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Playing around storing some log data in MongoDB. Now I need to fetch a list of what logs types there are actually stored in the collection.

I have a documents like this: ( pretend that could be thousand of each and more Groups and SubGroups )

```
{
  "Group": "Import",
  "SubGroup": "Update server"
},{
  "Group": "Import",
  "SubGroup": "Delete server"
}
```

I want to end up with something like:

```
{
  "Group": "Import",
  "SubGroups": ["Delete server", "Update server"]
}
```

But since there could be more of each SubGroup and I want want any duplicates ... does javascript have something like a HashKey set ... not really much of a js specialist here.

I'm going to use this for a gui so the user can select what type of logs he wants to see.

As a side question.
Since Mapreduce and the output type can be inline, replace and reduce. Are there any simple way built into MongoDB, so I can tell it to only update the MapReduce every x minutes since its actually very static or is it something I have to implement as cache in my own application layer?

Comment: Could you explain why you have documents structured like this in the first place? Why not just create/update your documents with the SubGroups as an array then you don't have to do any M/R updates at all.

Comment: Its like the Event viewer in Windows ... if I want to query againts it I need to know what types there are, Both Group and SubGroup ( There might be better names )

How would you else query againts it? Advice is very well received here. I used to working with SQL ... so the no-sql space is new. Maybe I'm doing it in a dump way now.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe update your example with more detail? You will have like a datestamp and error message with each object? And the SubGroups aren't a well-defined list of possible values?

Comment: Thats because I dont have the possible values for the Group and SubGroup and why I want to find them by doing the MapReduce. I'm starting to think that I should maintain them in a seperate collection in Mongo, instead of searching for all the possible values.

Might be doing this wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

> ... does javascript have something like a HashKey set

So everything in javascript *is* a hash table. Store your results like this and you get your hash with the same semantics:

```
{
  "Group": "Import",
  "SubGroups": { "Delete server": 1, "Update server": 1 }
}
```

> Since Mapreduce and the output type can be inline, replace and reduce.

My personal advice is to avoid the `inline`. If you're going to all of that effort to run a Map/Reduce, you might as well save the results.

That leaves you with `replace` and `reduce` and `merge` (options listed [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions)).

> its actually very static or is it something I have to implement as cache in my own application layer?

The output of a Map/Reduce is simply a collection. That collection has a specific format (`_id`, `value`), but it's a queryable collection like every other.

If you want to overwrite the summary data every 10 minutes, you can do so. However, this will mean that you have to run Map/Reduce across all of the data. This could represent an enormous amount of work in a logging system.

Instead, you probably want to run M/R on only the new parts of the data and then "re-reduce" against your existing summary data. This will be fastest.

Comment: Its not logging that much now, since is a hobby project but I might as well learn something by it. But thanks for the advice, I will look into it later tonight.

Love mongo ...